# What does "intention-behavior gap" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases, terminology

I know what do these all words mean separately, but I don't understand the meaning when they're used together. Can you explain it in simple terms and give examples of using this phrase?

Comment: **Context** would be helpful, but I _guess_ it's about a _gap_ between _intention_ and _behaviour_. In other words, I _want to_ make you happy, but what I actually _do_ is making you unhappy.

Comment: It's used in next sentence: "... announcing your goal widens your intention-behavior gap which is the disconnect between knowing you should do something and actually doing it."

Comment: Didn't you just answer your own question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "gap" refers to the difference between the intention, and the actual result of the behavior.

For instance, a child tries to be helpful by handing something to an adult, and ends up breaking it instead. There's a gap between intent (helpful) and behavior (break), which is *un*helpful.